# Sqlflite table does not exist

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am new with flutter, so let me know if I am missing anything. I have the folowing situation:

I am trying to create the table `entity`. The problem happens when I try to retrieve the data, I get an error saying that the table does not exist. This error does not happen when I insert into the same table. It is obvious that the table is not being created, so I would like to know what I am doing wrong on the creation.

Additionally, as the error is only being shown when I retrieve and not when I insert, I am curious about that. So, can someone explain me about this, like why it happens?

Below I am leaving the code that I think is necessary, please let me know if something else is needed.

```
Future<Database> createDatabase() {
  return getDatabasesPath().then((dbPath) {
    final String path = join(dbPath, "generic-app.db");
    return openDatabase(path, onCreate: (db, version) {
      db.execute("CREATE TABLE entity ("
          "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
          "titulo VARCHAR,"
          "subtitulo VARCHAR"
          ")");
    }, version: 1);
  });
}
```

The save() method that insert into the table:

```
Future<int> save(Entity entity) {
  return createDatabase().then((db) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> mapEntity = Map();
    mapEntity['id'] = entity.id;
    mapEntity['titulo'] = entity.titulo;
    mapEntity['subtitulo'] = entity.subtitulo;

    return db.insert("entity", mapEntity);
  });
}
```

The findAll() method that is throwing the exception:

```
Future<List<Entity>> findAll() {
 return createDatabase().then((db) {
    return db.query("entity").then((maps) {
      List<Entity> entities = List.empty(growable: true);
      for (Map<String, dynamic> map in maps) {
        Entity entity = Entity(
          map['id'],
          map['titulo'],
          map['subtitulo'],
        );
        entities.add(entity);
      }
      return entities;
    });
  });
}
```

The stacktrace shown:

```
E/SQLiteLog(21931): (1) no such table: entidade in "SELECT * FROM entity"
E/flutter (21931): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: 
DatabaseException(no such table: entity (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM 
entity) sql 'SELECT * FROM entity' args []
E/flutter (21931): #0      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:11:7)
E/flutter (21931): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21931): #1      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnRawQuery.<anonymous closure> 
(package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:404:30)
E/flutter (21931): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21931): #2      BasicLock.synchronized 
(package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:33:16)
E/flutter (21931): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21931): #3      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized 
(package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:344:14)
E/flutter (21931): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: make sure about version of you db is correct

Comment: Did you perhaps create the database without the table and then add the code for the table creation in the `onCreate` method, if that is the case the `onCreate` won't be called, you will need to either delete the database and start fresh or implement schema migration logic.